# I've got a very strange crash during Android TextAdventure development

Tags: java, android, crash, textview, android-tablelayout

http://scr.hu/0eug/7vny2

The situation:

I press a button that should launch this part of code (work in progress on this, it's not complete yet):

```
public void playerattack1(View view){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight_defense);
        displaystats();
        int attacktype = 1;
        int dmgminimum = 10;
        int dmgmaximum = 15;
        Random rn = new Random();
        int range = dmgmaximum - dmgminimum + 1;
        int damage = rn.nextInt(range) + dmgminimum;
        fight_p_attack(damage, attacktype);
        sb.insert(0,"Attack!\n");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teststring);
        textView.setText(sb);


public void fight_p_attack(int damage, int attacktype){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fight_defense);
        int k9minimum = 1;
        int k9maximum = 9;
        Random rn = new Random();
        int range = k9maximum - k9minimum + 1;
        int k9 = rn.nextInt(range) + k9minimum;

        switch (attacktype){
        case 1:
            switch (k9){
            case 1: damage *= 2;
            enemyhealth -= damage;
            case 4: enemyhealth -= damage;
            case 7: enemyhealth -= damage;
            }
        case 2:
            switch (k9){
            case 2: enemyhealth -= damage;
            case 5: damage *= 2;
            enemyhealth -= damage;
            case 8: enemyhealth -= damage;
            }
        case 3:
            switch (k9){
            case 3: enemyhealth -= damage;
            case 6: enemyhealth -= damage;
            case 9: damage *= 2;
            enemyhealth -= damage;
            }
        }
        fight_update();
    }

    public void fight_update(){
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.health);
        textView.setText("Health: "+health+" ");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mana);
        textView.setText("Mana: "+mana+" ");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gold);
        textView.setText("Gold: "+gold+" ");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.respect);
        textView.setText("Respect: "+respect);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enemyhealthView);
        textView.setText(enemyhealth);
    }
```

I've tested a bit and it seems that if I remove part trying to setText to a TextView inside a table view:

```
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enemyhealthView);
    textView.setText(enemyhealth);
```

It's no longer crashing (but obviously the table will be empty and that's not what I want!

Question: how do I write to such table:

http://scr.hu/0eug/zzqz1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/papier_1" >
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView android:id="@+id/health"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                <TextView android:id="@+id/mana"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                                <TextView android:id="@+id/gold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                                                        <TextView android:id="@+id/respect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tabla_cabecera" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/fightView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="@string/enemyname"></TextView>

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/fightView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="@string/health"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/enemyhealthView" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" ></TextView>

                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/fightView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="@string/attack"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/fightView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" ></TextView></TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">                    

                    <TextView  android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/fightView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:text="@string/defense"></TextView>
                    <TextView android:background="@drawable/cell_shape" android:padding="5dp" android:id="@+id/fightView5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" ></TextView>

                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>

                                        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playerattack1"
            android:text="@string/playerattack1" />
                                        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playerattack2"
            android:text="@string/playerattack2" />
                                        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="playerattack3"
            android:text="@string/playerattack3" />

                                                                        <TextView android:id="@+id/teststring"
                                    android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: the layout you posted is active_fight_defense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your stack trace image

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b

You will get this Exception, when you are tring to set int value to the `TextView`, or `Edittext` or `Button`, `Toast` etc views.

When you set the int value to the views, it will consider them as String resources, it will try to search for the string resource with the specified id, and will throw `Resources$NotFoundException`

Change this

```
textView.setText(enemyhealth);
```

to

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(enemyhealth));
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, I will try that... but how would you explain that this part works?

Comment: because the others are string. enemyhealth is a integer. Android will look for a String with that enemyhealth's value

Comment: `public void displaystats(){
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.health);
  textView.setText("Życie: "+health+" ");
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mana);
  textView.setText("Mana: "+mana+" ");
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gold);
  textView.setText("Złoto: "+gold+" ");
  textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.respect);
  textView.setText("Respekt: "+respect);
 }`

Comment: Well anyway i've been using this above^ part since i started working on my text adventure. But i guess the fact that i start setText with "string" and THEN add +integer solves the problem. I've used @Pragnani code and it works now... Thanks!!!

Comment: @Dravic Reason is already mentioned by blackbelt, `setText` method will also accept string resource id as the argument. So when ever you supply `int` value it will consider that as String resource id

Comment: Oki, oki, I get it, i was just curious why this works: `textView.setText("Health: "+enemyhealth+" ");` And once again, thank you so much for help guys!

Comment: @Dravic This is normal string `"Health: "+enemyhealth+" "` is a string, so There won't be any problem